# How to Mock private functions that returns a promise karma unit test

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I want to test a function(publicFunction) inside a factory(TestFactory). This functions calls a private function(privateFunction) that returns a promise with calling andother function(Caller) inside another factory(callerfactory). How do I mock that private function?

```html
module.factory('TestFactory',['callerfactory','$q',function($q,callerfactory){


  function privateFunction(varr){

   var deferred = $q.defer( );
   var data = new Caller(varr);
   varr.init().then( function( ) {
        deferred.resolve( vari );         //This is important to be resolved
      } );

      return deferred.promise;
   }
   
   
  this.publicFunction = function(list){
  
   var promises = [];
  
   angular.forEach(list.find('ind'), function (sampleVar,index) {
  
    promises.push( privateFunction(sampleVar));
   }
   $q.all(promises).then ( function (status) ) {
  
    Varriedlist = status;                //I want to test if this list whould be filled
    deferred.resolve( true );
   }
  
   return deferred.promise;
   }
} ] );
```

And the Caller factoy:

```html
module.factory( 'callerfactory', function() {

  var caller = function (varToCall) {
  
    var _varToCall= this;
  
    this.init = function () {
       var deferred = $q.defer( );
   
       //some implementations
     
       return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
  return caller;
}
```

I am using karma for unit test and jasmine 2 framework.